# What role did wizards play in the British Empire?

Tags: harry-potter

In http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Quidditch_teams I counted 13 British-affiliated countries (including England, Canada, USA) , 11 European countries, 5 French-affiliated,2 Spanish-affiliated,2 Portuguese-affiliated countries.

British colonies seem well-represented here. British Muggles used colonies to enhance their wealth. They imposed their language and culture to the native people. They built cricket clubs.

I guess Quiddich became international since Wizards have managed to establish a parallel "Wizard state" within the colonies too. But did the Wizards share Muggle motivations of getting rich off colonies and imposing their culture?

What role did wizards play in the British Empire?

Comment: @RogueJedi, USA (and Australia as another example) were English-settled.

Comment: @RogueJedi I think he's asking about the *historical* British Empire, of which the US colonies were part.

Comment: Any reasons for the downvotes?

Comment: @RogueJedi Yes, but before there was a war to make them not "British-affiliated" they were "British-affiliated".

Comment: And they will be again one day muhahahahahahahahah

Comment: It will happen. http://thedcbrief.tumblr.com/post/136881446140/the-queen-of-england-promises-to-take-back

Comment: Doubtful. More likely that China will end up with the not so British, British settled colonies before the British do.

Comment: See my answer for http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116021/does-the-wizarding-world-have-a-european-union.  It talks about how the ministry of magic is not exactly a parallel wizard state.

Answer (score 1):

Some (slightly relevant) background information: The [British Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Empire) historically came into being in **1583** when American expansion began. In **1707**, the Kingdoms of England and Scotland merged to form the Kingdom of Great Britain. The American Revolution of 1765-1783 led the British Empire to turn eastward, commencing global expansion and eventually becoming the world's largest empire in recorded history. Following Napoleon's defeat, the Pax Britannica - the British Imperial Century of 1815-1914 - dawned on the British Empire.

The British wizarding community was governed by the [Wizards' Council](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wizards%27_Council) since medieval times until 1707, when it was replaced by the [Ministry of Magic](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/British_Ministry_of_Magic), which is considered to be "a more highly structured, organised and complex government structure". The nature of these two governing bodies and the history behind their transitions tell us about the roles the wizarding community played in British history, if any.

### Before the British Empire

- The Wizards' Council appeared to emulate a tribal power structure, its leader being given the title of Chief. The loose, informal nature of such a governing body, coupled with the feudal state of the kingdom at the time, meant that the English were unlikely to have access to wizards in an institutionalised and systematic manner, nor anything approaching a military scale.
- The presence of Merlin did imply that the English court had access to wizards at an individual level. Such court wizards were indeed involved in national affairs.
- The existence of martial magic and the title of Warlock today hints at a possible history of the usage of magic in warfare at some point in the distant past, medieval or earlier.

### Early Empire

- As the world emerged from the feudal era, the royal courts of Europe began to consolidate power. The Wizards' Council also evolved in reflection of the changing times, becoming more bureaucratic and institutionalised. As an example, a medieval law passed in 1362 to ban Quidditch near Muggle settlements was a simplistic, straightforward one-liner, while the 1631 Code of Wand Use had a legally recognised name, for starters, and was organised into clauses and such modern legal jargon. This suggests that the English government could have access to previously unavailable wizarding resources and powers if it wished to, theoretically.
- However, anti-wizard sentiments started rising alongside the trend of witch hunts since the early 15th century:

> "As the witch-hunts grew ever fiercer, wizarding families began to live double lives, using charms of concealment to protect themselves and their families. By the seventeenth century, any witch or wizard who chose to fraternise with Muggles became suspect, even an outcast in his or her own community." - *Albus Dumbledore*

- Such circumstances meant that wizards were increasingly reluctant to reveal their identities, so their involving in national affairs were expected to decrease, increasingly focused on self-governance alone.

### 1707

After a final, failed attempt to seek official recognition and protection by the British monarchy, the International Confederation of Wizards finally resorted to passing the International Statute of Wizarding Secrecy, in order to save themselves before the witch hunts escalate into any anti-wizard genocide. It was signed in 1689 and enacted in 1692. In 1707, the Ministry of Magic was established to replace the Wizards' Council, in order to effectively enforce the Statute of Secrecy within the British Empire.

> "Upon the signature of the International Statute of Secrecy in 1689, wizards went into hiding for good." - *Bathilda Bagshot*

### Later Empire

With the wizarding world hidden in secrecy from the Muggle world since 1689, there are no intentional wizard involvement in the affairs of the British Empire from that point.

Comment: Just read a question about Grindelwald, could argue that in the later Empire, they asked Dumbledore to defeat Grindelwald to stop WW2?

Comment: @user3564421 According to http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Global_wizarding_war Rowling appears to like having magic events occur in parallel to their Muggle equivalent, but in-universe the two are not necessarily related, and the timing is usually coincidence.

Comment: @user3564421 The GWW isn't technically a part of WWII (although because of the scale of the wars and the chaos of the times, the magical world overlapped with the Muggle world for a while, and the two wars fed each other, keeping each other going). GWW just happens to occur at the same time as WWII. Dumbledore was asked to intervene with Grindelwald by the wizarding community, not the British government. The defeat of Grindelwald in 1945 is, also, a coincidence (in-universe-wise, as per Rowling's intent).

Comment: @user3564421 If you meant WWII specifically and not the GWW, however, I haven't seen anything to suggest Dumbledore was asked to intervene in fighting the Axis Powers.

Comment: Is there any mention of Wizards living in the colonies?

Comment: There are wizards in the USA...how do you think they came to be there? Also don't forget that the earliest colonists to the New World are those who do not "fit in" to society at home back in Europe.

Comment: @thegreatjedi true, but you said it yourself though, they fed each other...kept each other going? if grindelwald was defeated, they could not feed off each other meaning dumbledore has a link in defeating the axis through defeating grindelwald? the prime minister of england could also have asked help from the minister for magic, who then asked dumbledore.

Comment: I'm repeating exactly what Rowling supposedly said. Her idea is that the two wars fed each other. She didn't elaborate. In general, however, when such language is used it suggests that consequential events in each war contributed to prolonging the other war, usually by coincidence or as a side effect.