# Does the Wizarding World have a European Union?

Tags: harry-potter, government

In the Harry Potter universe, we have mention of the Ministry of Magic (which is the UK governing body) and the International Confederation of Wizards, which is meant to be the Wizarding World's United Nations.

Is there a version of the European Union in the Wizarding World?

Comment: There's not much mention of anything outside the UK.

Comment: @randal'thor There is at least mention of the Confederation, although it's mostly in mentions.

Comment: Just imagine your cauldron laws won't fly as some watery tart in Brussels said 'no'.

Comment: There certainly is something like the EU or UN in effect, which was probably in effect long before the Muggle UN or EU existed. Whilst it is never mentioned, the characters don't get into any situation where that would matter... they never leave England, never have to change currencies, show passports & only dealt with foreign nationals during the Triwizard tournament, but it's held at Hogwarts.

Comment: We already know about the EU countires which attended Quidditch World Cup which is moderated by an international cooperation. In the light of recent developments in _Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them_ there is a mention of governing organ of magial beings known as [MACUSA](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Magical_Congress_of_the_United_States_of_America). Turns out every country that has magical people in it have some sort of governing part national or international. It's only logical we assume international parties have a common ground when it comes to solve international matters.

Comment: Anyway that I can improve on [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/123816/55866)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that in Britain, there's both a Muggle government and a Ministry of Magic.  The Ministry of magic deals with magical Law Enforcement, Magical Accidents and Catastrophes, Magical Creatures, Magical Cooperation, Magical Transportation, Magical Games and Sports and [Magical] Mysteries.  In other words, the MoM deals with only the magic in Britain while leaving the governing of the actual country to the Muggle government.  Magical Cooperation deals with things like the Quidditch World Cup, Triwizard Tournament, and International laws and standard cauldron thickness.  So while I could not find anything in canon, it is extremely unlikely that there is a political Union such as the EU in the magical world.

Comment: Actually, wouldn't Percy's work on cauldron norms as part of international magical cooperation suggest that there are international norms and regulations ? We don't know if they emanate from the ICW or another body. It could be a wizarding EU. Don't get me wrong, I don't think there would be one, as wizards have had functional worldwide institutions since the 1600s (Statute of Secrecy -> ICW), so there would be no point for them in replicating the EU in the 1950s. But I  can't really understand your reasoning :)

Comment: I'm saying that there is a difference between international regulations and onternational political unions

Answer (score 10):

### The Medieval Assembly of European Wizards

> Harry found Ron at the back of the library, measuring his History of Magic homework. Professor Binns had asked for a three foot long composition on “**The Medieval Assembly of European Wizards**.”
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets - Chapter 9*)</sub>

While this governing body may very well no longer be around by the times of the main Harry Potter books, it is the closest example we know of a Wizarding World equivalent for the European Union.

It should also be noted that [in the movie universe, this organisation still exists in the present day](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/0/0a/The_Medieval_Assembly_of_European_Wizards.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20080718183854). Of course, none of that is canon because the movies are nonsense.